# Browser and Node import statement incompatibility

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, browser

In Node, one can conditionalize `require()` statements in several ways -- put them inside `if` or other conditional statements, use `?:` for the target to be required, put them in a function that is conditionally called. By contrast, `import` statements have no such flexibility. So, if I have a module that will that will refer to a file when running on Node but will work in a different way when running in the browser, I cannot do anything equivalent to `const fs = inBrowser ? null : require("fs");`

So, how does one use a module in Node and also in the browser when such conditionality is needed?

Also, `require()` and `import` statements within Node commonly use relative paths. In the browser, it seems the norm (the requirement?) is to use absolute url's. So, can I have a module, say at the url /assets/mod1.mjs, import another module with something like `import { x } from "./specialPlace/mod2.mjs";` and have that work in the browser, or must every `import` be an absolute path? If we do that for the browser, it won't work in Node since there is not root from an absolute path other than something like `/usr/person/...` and that won't work in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `import` on demand like `require` you can call it as a function. It's called [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import). Returns a promise of the imported module (Module instance). Usually you use `await` with it. `await` without `async` is supported on the top-level of modules.

Nowadays I recommend using ESM in node.js too and migrate from `require`. Recent version of many NPM modules dropped support for CommonJS in favor of ESM.

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
const {default: myModule} = doINeedModule ? await import('myModule') : {default: null};
```

Also managing, bundling and resolving bare and file-system imports is done by bundlers. Working without a bundler is like stone-aged currently if the target is the browser.

I recommend [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/). With plugins you could not bother even importing anything, that will be done for you automatically. You can write custom bare and file-system resolvers, possibilities are endless. You can even import modules by file name patterns: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

Comment: I concur and am in the process of migrating my node code to use import. I had bumped into ```await import()```, but did not know that it allowed the conditionalization that is not supported for "bare" imports.  The snippet you provided is just the sort of thing I need. What about a module importing another module via a relative path. Does that survive use in the browser (I am about to test it)? I was using Browserify, but for some reason it could not find a certain node_module that was clearly present. I know it's "ancient" so I was looking for an alternative. I'll look at Vite. -- Thanks.

Comment: @BennettBarouch a bare import is that does start with an alpha character (not relative or absolute path or url - these are file system/url imports). relative paths in imports should work in browsers

Comment: @BennettBarouch if you find answer useful don't hesitate to accept it (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up), thanks